# gif image not changing frames in a label

Tags: c#, .net, image, label, gif

I am using an ajax loader gif image as a label background and before calling a time consuming method, I am setting this label visible and making it invisible after the method call. Problem is the gif image is being shown, but it is a still image, it is not changing frames. Below is my code:

```
labelWait.Visible=true;
SomeLibrary.SomeClass.SomeMethod();
labelWait.Visible=false;
```

What can be the way out?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are doing this on the server side. Now, I don't know what you've been using for your AJAX call, I'll assume it's jQuery.

The normal flow of doing this kind of thing goes like this:

1. On the client side (the web page) the user click on a button (or a link);
2. Show an element with the animated gif;
3. Do the jQuery.ajax call;
4. The server do its work and the request come back;
5. Do stuff with the response;
6. Hide the element with the animated gif.

Code would be something like:

**SomePage.aspx (or cshtml if mvc)**

```
<a href="#" id="dosomething">Load some stuff...</a>
<div id="loader" style="display: none;"><img src="loader.gif"/></div>
<div id="mydata"/>

<script>
  $("#dosomething").click(function() {
    $("#loader").show();
    $.ajax({
      url: '/somewheretogetdata',
      success: function(data) {
        $("#mydata").html(data);
        $("#loader").hide();
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Of course, /somewheretogetdata should execute your code:

```
SomeLibrary.SomeClass.SomeMethod();
```